# Geb: Writing report file for test failure

Tags: maven, report, spock, geb

Geb is taking screen shots as .png file and DOM elements as a html file in the configured report directory while executing test cases.

I need also to write the test failure details like below in a file because I have to submit the failure result:

```
title == "SomeTitleHere"
|     |
|     false
SomeAnotherTitleHere
```

How can I achieve this or what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a good solution on writing test failure details in an HTML format.
As I created the project as a Maven project in Eclipse[Mars], adding the following dependency in pom.xml will create the .html report files in the build directory.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.athaydes</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock-reports</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <!-- this avoids affecting your version of Groovy/Spock -->
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>*</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- // if you don't already have slf4j-api and an implementation of it in the     classpath, add this! -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.13</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.13</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```